# why is Youtube loading so fast, I tried many time with my flutter code, every time I move the progress,

Tags: html, firebase, flutter, dart

how can Youtube be loading that quickly. I tried many time with my flutter code, every time I move the progress bar, it can load so quickly and responsively, but I could not achieve the same efficiency in my code, is there any way to achieve it? thank you, or is there any error with code to modify to improve the speed of the video loading

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChewieDemo(),
  );
}

class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Chewie Demo'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
  TargetPlatform _platform;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/asdasdas.mp4');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      // Try playing around with some of these other options:

      // showControls: false,
      // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
      //   playedColor: Colors.red,
      //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      // ),
      // placeholder: Container(
      //   color: Colors.grey,
      // ),
      // autoInitialize: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController2.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your code and everything to do with the server that is serving the video,

It looks like you are pulling the file from github.

using a [CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn/) will help speed load times on your external content.

Comment: sorry, sir, can you teach me how to speed it up with Cloudflare as it got too little experience on this, thank you.

Comment: First you need to [create a static file server](https://medium.com/shovel-apps/simple-node-js-server-on-heroku-210ec24f485) then you will need to set your CDN up to serve files from that server. I couldnt find any simple tutorials for CloudFlare, however, [Fastly CDN](https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/start-here) has some very nice documentation on getting started.

Comment: Mr. Burgess, thank you for helping, I experimented with it for the whole night and now got a little sense of how to use it, i still have another question which is whether the files being sped up should be from my own database? what is the file is is publicly downloadable like I stored it in firebase, can that be facilitated by Cloudflare? thank you